# About equivalent measure on $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $m$ denote the canonical Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mu$ be a regular Borel measure on $\mathbb{R}^n$, if for all open balls $B \subset \mathbb{R}$, we have
$$C_1\ m(B)\leq \mu(B) \leq C_2 m(B)$$
for some positive $C_1>0,C_2>0$. The problems asks to show $\mu,m$ is mutually absolutely continuous.

The conclusion will following immediately if we can show
$$C_1\ m(E)\leq \mu(E) \leq C_2 m(E)$$
for all Borel set $E$. By regularity it shall be sufficient to reduce this to the case for open set $E$. If we are dealing with dimension 1, then any open set can be decomposed as countable disjoint open intervals and we are done. But for $n\geq 2$, open set does not generally admit such decomposition(i.e. the union of disjoint open balls). Though it is obviously that open sets can be covered with open balls within any given error in measure, it is hard to expect we can take some cover of disjoint balls, so the argument still does not hold. I am not sure if this approach to the proof works, any comment shall be greatly appreciated!

[Editted]

Thanks to the comment below I have reached conclusion by another approach. Now I have another question: If we let $f:=d\mu / dm$, then intuitively $f$ should be bounded both from below and above, i.e. $f,1/f \in L^\infty(m)$, does this hold true?

Comment: Try proving that the class of sets satisfying that relation is a $\sigma$-algebra. For instance, it is clearly closed under countable disjoint union. Complements might take some work, but perhaps you can restrict to bounded sets and use the Caratheodory condition .. not sure about details.

Comment: I would try with the Lebesgue decomposition $\mu=\mu_c+\mu_s$ w.r.t. $m$. You have to show that the the singular part $\mu_s$ vanishes. By regularity, it would be enough to show that it vanishes on open sets and for this it is enough that it vanishes on open balls.

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan I think it would be a great approach if we can first deal with case of infinite measure, then simply by monotone-class argument we can conclude..but it seems a little tricky

Comment: @Jochen Got it! very illuminating!

Comment: Regarding your edit, what would happen if $\operatorname{ess-sup}f>C_2$ (w.r.t. $m$)? What if $\operatorname{ess-inf}f<C_1$?

Comment: @JonathanY. Since we are dealing with lower bound and upper bound, conditions like $||f||_{\infty}>C_2$ does not give contradiction immediately

Answer (score 1):

To prove that $f$ and $1/f$ are in $L^{\infty}$: if $E$ is a Borel set, then $$C_1m(E)\leq\mu(E)=\int_Efdm\Rightarrow\int_E(f-C_1)dm\geq 0.$$ Since this is true for all Borel subsets of $\mathbb R^n$, you have that $f\geq C_1$ almost everywhere. Similarly, $f\leq C_2$ almost everywhere.

Comment: I am not yet reaching the conclusion for all Borel sets, but balls shall be sufficient if we consider Lebesgue point of $f$. Thank you for you hint!

Answer (score 1):

I submit a possible answer based on the heuristic principle "boxes are the same as balls", which I have sometimes heard at seminars in real analysis.

Let $E\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be open. We can decompose $E$ into a countable and disjoint union of dyadic boxes: 
$$E=\bigcup_{j=0}^\infty D_j.$$
Therefore we only need to prove that 
$$\tag{1} c m(D_j)\le \mu(D_j)\le C m(D_j),\qquad \forall j.$$ 
To prove this we fix $j$ and we let $b$ and $B$ denote two concentric balls such that 
$$b\subset D_j\subset B.$$
We can arrange things so that the ratio $\frac{m(B)}{m(b)}$ is a constant, not depending on $j$. Since 
$$\mu(b)\le \mu(D_j)\le \mu(B), $$
we infer 
$$C_1 m(b)\le \mu(D_j)\le C_2m(B).$$
It is also true that
$$m(b)\le m(D_j)\le m(B), $$
so we have for the ratio $\mu(D_j)/m(D_j)$ 
$$C_1 \frac{m(b)}{m(B)}\le \frac{\mu(D_j)}{m(D_j)}\le C_2\frac{m(B)}{m(b)}.$$
This is (1) with $c=C_1 \frac{m(b)}{m(B)}$ and $C=C_2\frac{m(B)}{m(b)}.$

Comment: If we can show the inequality holds true for the canonical semiring on $\mathbb{R}^n$, then by monotone-class argument we can do this immediately. The question is, however, how should we approximate the dyadic box by open balls.

Comment: Just take $b$ to be an inscribed ball and $B=2\sqrt{n}b$. There is no need for abstract measure theory arguments, IMHO.